# Why does bundle install not use the version of bundler in Gemfile though its available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

When I do a

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

on my app, I get the following error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    bundler (= 1.0.18) java

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.1.5)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

My gem list shows that I have the mentioned gem

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.5, 1.0.22, 1.0.18)
```

My gem file looks like this

```
gem "rake", "0.9.2"
gem "activerecord-jdbc-adapter", "1.2.0"
gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", "1.2.0"
gem "acts_as_tree", "0.1.1"
gem "bundler", "1.0.18", :require => "bundler"
gem "database_cleaner", "0.6.7"
gem "jdbc-mysql", "5.1.13"
gem "jruby-jars", "1.6.2"
gem "jruby-rack", "1.1.3"
gem "jruby-openssl", "0.7.4"
gem "net-scp", "1.0.4"
gem "net-ssh", "2.2.1"
gem 'uuidtools', "2.1.1"
gem 'nokogiri', "1.5.0"
```

How do I fix this? I use jruby-1.6.3 and rails 3.0.10.

Comment: Why are you specifying a bundler version? And anyway, bundler shouldn't be in the Gemfile since it's the program that processes Gemfiles!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to 
 - either remove bundler from the gemfile
 - set it to the bundler version to use to bundle it
 - or vice versa: use the bundler version to bundle that you require in the gem file

but as Anthony said, do you have a reason for including it in the Gemfile ?

Comment: Well, the project required this specific version of bundler as there were other dependencies on the specific version

Comment: I would then try the second option - running the bundler version that is required in the gemfile, I would try if bundle exec bundle works.

Comment: using bundle exec just created a new error 'Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.0.10) java' in the gems available on this machine'. A gem list rails does show that version of rails.